# Create a time series window with Spark SQL in WSO2 DAS

Tags: wso2, apache-spark-sql, wso2-das

I need to create a time series window to do some analysis in WSO2 DAS.

Suppose we have a sensor that each second sends a "fault" attribute and a "temperature" attribute:

```
{"fault": false, "temperature": 29}
{"fault": false, "temperature": 21}
{"fault": false, "temperature": 30}
{"fault": false, "temperature": 28}
{"fault": false, "temperature": 23}
{"fault": false, "temperature": 22}
{"fault": false, "temperature": 26}
```

Then we want to create a window of 2 consecutive temperature values:

```
t1, t2
------
29, 21
21, 30
30, 28
etc...
```

In order to do this I try to run in the Interactive Analytics Console a spark SQL query like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE SAMPLE_TYPE_EVENTS USING CarbonAnalytics OPTIONS (tableName "IOT_PER_DEVICE_STREAM_CARBON_SUPER_SAMPLETYPE", recordStore "EVENT_STORE", schema "temperature INT,fault BOOLEAN,meta_deviceId STRING, _timestamp LONG");
SELECT temperature, LAG(temperature) OVER (PARTITION BY meta_deviceId ORDER BY _timestamp) FROM SAMPLE_TYPE_EVENTS;
```

but I get the following error:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-09-29 17:02:21,075] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.admin.AnalyticsProcessorAdminService} -  Error while executing query : select temperature, lag(temperature) over (partition by meta_deviceId order by _timestamp) FROM SAMPLE_TYPE_EVENTS; {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.admin.AnalyticsProcessorAdminService}
org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.exception.AnalyticsExecutionException: Exception in executing query select temperature, lag(temperature) over (partition by meta_deviceId order by _timestamp) FROM SAMPLE_TYPE_EVENTS;
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.internal.SparkAnalyticsExecutor.executeQueryLocal(SparkAnalyticsExecutor.java:764)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.internal.SparkAnalyticsExecutor.executeQuery(SparkAnalyticsExecutor.java:721)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.CarbonAnalyticsProcessorService.executeQuery(CarbonAnalyticsProcessorService.java:201)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.admin.AnalyticsProcessorAdminService.executeQuery(AnalyticsProcessorAdminService.java:336)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:169)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:82)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender.finalizeSendWithToAddress(CarbonLocalTransportSender.java:45)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender.invoke(LocalTransportSender.java:77)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.admin.stub.AnalyticsProcessorAdminServiceStub.executeQuery(AnalyticsProcessorAdminServiceStub.java:2647)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.ui.client.AnalyticsExecutionClient.execute(AnalyticsExecutionClient.java:63)
    at org.apache.jsp.spark_002dmanagement.execute_005fsparkquery_005fajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(execute_005fsparkquery_005fajaxprocessor_jsp.java:109)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1770)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1729)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.55] failure: ``union'' expected but `(' found

select temperature, lag(temperature) over (partition by meta_deviceId order by _timestamp) FROM X1234_SAMPLE_TYPE_EVENTS
                                          ^
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.AbstractSparkSQLParser.parse(AbstractSparkSQLParser.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.DefaultParserDialect.parse(ParserDialect.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$2.apply(SQLContext.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$2.apply(SQLContext.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSQLParser$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$SparkSQLParser$$others$1.apply(SparkSQLParser.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSQLParser$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$SparkSQLParser$$others$1.apply(SparkSQLParser.scala:113)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Success.map(Parsers.scala:136)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Success.map(Parsers.scala:135)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Parsers.scala:242)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Parsers.scala:242)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:222)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Failure.append(Parsers.scala:202)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:222)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$2$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Parsers.scala:891)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$2$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Parsers.scala:891)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$2.apply(Parsers.scala:890)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$$anon$1.apply(PackratParsers.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.AbstractSparkSQLParser.parse(AbstractSparkSQLParser.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$1.apply(SQLContext.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$1.apply(SQLContext.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DDLParser.parse(DDLParser.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.parseSql(SQLContext.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:817)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.spark.core.internal.SparkAnalyticsExecutor.executeQueryLocal(SparkAnalyticsExecutor.java:760)
    ... 76 more
```

Why am I getting this error?

For those of you that don't know WSO2 DAS, it is a GUI that wraps the spark environment, so I don't have some "code" but only the SQL query that i paste into a console like this:

[image: WSO2 DAS Spark console]

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.55] failure: ``union'' expected but `(' found , could you please share complete code.

Comment: @vaquarkhan if I well understood your request I don't have some code, because WSO2 DAS is a GUI Tool. I added a screenshot in the original question for you to see. Thanks

Comment: I am not expert in WSO2 DAS is a GUI Tool may be following link will help .https://wso2.org/jira/browse/DAS-12